# Cannot connect on SQL developer to a database on fresh installation on oracle 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I just installed oracle 12c standard edition to test compatibility for database that will be migrated to oracle 12c from oracle 10g.

I installed it succesfully, it gave me the url of my database (https://localhost:5500/em) and I chose an SID (TEST). Then I create a new user and import the .dmp file of the database I had on Oracle 10g. So far so good.

Then I connect to the user and check around, tables are imported, insertions also, good.

Then I try to connect from sql developer... No way to do it.

Question I have:

- As I have 2 installations of oracle, what is the port of the listener of the second installation? Is there a way to check it? Normally the port of the listener is 1521 but as I have now two installations, no idea.

I have tried every single combination of sid and port but nothing works. It was so easy to configure it with oracle 10/11g so of course I know I am misunderstanding something. I have looked for info to see the ports and I saw that there is a file called portlist.ini but it is empty.

Any help or guidance to go throw the issue would help me a lot, I have been like 6 hours researching and trying to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to run two listeners. It may have configured a second one (perhaps also on 1521) but not started it; or been unable to start it; or it is on a different port and/or address. What address and port is the original 10g listener on, and what is the LOCAL_LISTENER system parameter set to on both? And what does `lnsrctl status` say from both the 10g and 12c environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've installed your 12c as a container database. This makes connecting a bit different. Try connecting by service_name not by tns. This is as in previous versions.

This may be helpful: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-connecting-to-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1

Answer (score 1):

For the listener port you should check your listener.ora file.
You also can get these information from the output of:

```
lsnrctl stat
```